# WWW::Mechanize for search-as-you-type

Tags: perl, forms, web-scraping

I am trying to automate interaction with a website which has a 'search-as-you-type' searchbar that is not embedded within a form. Here's part of the html:

```
<div id="search-box">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="input-outer">
                <div class="input-inner">
                    <input class="xblur" id="q" name="q" title="type to begin search" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cancel" class="activated" title="Clear search">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I can deal with forms, and so far scripting has gone fine, but now I seem to have hit a roadblock... How can I conduct a search in such a case, preferably using `WWW::Mechanize` (but a different module or so would also be fine)?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as troubleshooting this goes, I would suggest installing the Firebug plugin into Firefox.  Go to the search form page and enable Firebug. Make sure the console tab is the active so that you can see what is happening as you type.  You should be able to get a better sense of what is happening as far as AJAX goes by watching for GET or POST requests as you interact with the form.

Firebug also has an arrow icon which you can click and then select page elements in order to view the source.  This is very handy for getting the names of form elements which have been created *after* the page has loaded.

You can also click on requests which appear in the console to see both the request and response returned.  This information can be very valuable.

Once you have this information you can decide how to handle getting past the search form.  If you can see which parameters are being sent to the search form you may well be better off POSTing to the target of the search rather than filling out the form and clicking on it via mech.

```
$mech->post( $url, { foo => 'bar', name => 'value' } );
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all those details, I've just sat down to work on it again, so I'm sure they'll come in very handy.

Answer (score 1):

So you need execute the JS in the page? [Mozilla::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mozilla%3a%3aMechanize), [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aIE%3a%3aMechanize)

Comment: I don't actually know. I am new to this and I have never worked with Javascript, so I might be wrong, but to me it looks like the JS on that page only has to do with Twitter-following and Google Analytics. I can't find any script that might be involved in the search, but then again perhaps I simply don't know how to look!?

Comment: What happens when you type into that box? If it's anything other than the browser's simple autocompleter, there's some scripting involved.

Comment: Safari or Chrome's WebInspector or Firebug in Firefox will help you figure out what requests (if any) the browser is sending as you type.

Comment: What @Ask Bjørn Hansen is possibly getting at is that another possibility is to figure out what's going on and re-implement it in Perl.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. When I type in the box the search starts immediately. Also I think I might have found (one of) the responsible part(s): "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/..."  I'll keep investigating - thanks again!